# Why does JavaScript dialog boxes (alert, confirm) stop page redrawing?

Tags: javascript, browser

Opening an modal dialog box on a browser page, stops the page from redrawing.
Scripts started asynchronously run uninterrupted in the background.

I illustrate the behaviour in this JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YNbux/. The box stops its animation when the `alert()` is shown and jumps in the animation when the alert is closed.

This behaviour is present in (on my computer at least):

- Chrome 21.0.1180.82
- Opera 12.01
- Safari 6.0

So I guess it is intended behaviour - but causes animations to jump, and other things that would seem as glitches to an end user. So why does `alert()` and `confirm()` stop pages from redrawing?

**Edit:**
gif-images also stop redrawing:  http://jsfiddle.net/YNbux/4/

Comment: If you want to make a non-blocking dialog box, yopu can create you own, or use something like jQueryUI's `dialog` functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those functions are blocking functions.  Your JavaScript stops executing until they return.

Your animations and what not in the background are not completely separated from your code calling `alert()`.  Code that appears to be asynchronous still need to execute in the loop, and if some code blocks that loop, they will not run on their own.  This is critical to proper operation of your code.

Comment: But if you wait a little while before dismissing them, you'll see that the animation has in fact "completed".

Comment: @BoltClock I think that's a jQuery "feature". It probably uses the time passed since the beginning to know how much to increase the co-ordinates by. To prove my point, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/YNbux/1/ Hit okay on the alert ASAP.

Comment: @BoltClock, jQuery is basing its animation of time.  Time has passed, so the animation appears to jump ahead.  You cannot predict a "frame rate" of the browser, so this is how they calculate the positions.

Comment: and thus why ` alert ` and ` confirm ` should be avoided for almost all cases.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, ... unless you want to block, which is completely appropriate in many cases.

Comment: Okay I agree that JavaScript halts until the alert-box is closed: http://jsfiddle.net/YNbux/6/ (pops up a window, but only after closing the alert box). But that doesn't explain why the gif-image stops updating.

Comment: @qff, How and when a browser chooses to update an animated GIF is entirely up to it.  It makes sense that the JavaScript and GIF rendering threads may be interlocked in some way, or even the same thread, depending on implementation.